# Refresh issue with Stored Procedure in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

I have one SP for mobile application chat app (used with API) it has  25 filters and 10 tables join and return posts for user, it works good for 2 days but after 2 days it stop working, then i need to refresh it again with alter query or something  then  it start working for next few days.

If filter stop for any particular user than why others have issue with SP.

```
    USE [DatabaseName]GOSET ANSI_NULLS ONGOSET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ONGOALTER PROC [dbo].[uspGetShoutouts] (
    @UserId  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @anotherUserid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Interest NVARCHAR(100),
    @Gender NVARCHAR(100),
    @AgeFrom INT,
    @AgeTo  INT,
    @StartLatitude NUMERIC(20,15),
    @StartLongitude NUMERIC(20,15),
    @Radius FLOAT,
    @Location BIT = NULL,
    @IsTraveler BIT,
    @IsLocal BIT,
    @HomeTownCity VARCHAR(100),
    @UserName NVARCHAR(200),
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(200),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(200),
    @CreatedDate DATETIME,
    @IsMyShoutout BIT,
    @ShoutoutTypeId INT=0,
    @PostTypeId INT=0,
    @oldMoment BIT,
    @SortExpression CHAR(1) = 1,
    @CurrentPage INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @IsFriend BIT=0,
    @IsPrivate BIT,
    @GroupId NVARCHAR(200),
    @TotalRows INT OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserList TABLE(
    UserId uniqueidentifier,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
    LastName NVARCHAR(100),
    QuickBloxId NVARCHAR(100),
    SocialId NVARCHAR(100),
    Gender char(1),
    Email NVARCHAR(100),
    IsProfileImageSync bit,
    IsFriend bit,
    IsRequestSent bit,
    RequestSender NVARCHAR(100),
    IsBlocked bit,
    FriendBlocked  bit,
    Age int,
    HomeTownCity NVARCHAR(100),
    ImageName NVARCHAR(200),
    Distance numeric(20,6),
    DistanceTemp numeric(20,6),
    LastActiveDateTime datetime,
    ShoutoutGuid uniqueidentifier,
    ShoutoutId bigint not null,
    InterestId int,
    InterestName NVARCHAR(100),
    ShoutoutImageName NVARCHAR(200),
    Description  NVARCHAR(max),
    CreatedOn DateTime,
    IsImageSync bit,
    DisplayUpdatedOn NVARCHAR(50),
    ShoutoutCity NVARCHAR(500),
    ShoutoutCountry NVARCHAR(500),
    AdministrativeAreaLevel1 NVARCHAR(500),
    PlaceId NVARCHAR(500),
    FormattedAaddress NVARCHAR(500),
    Url NVARCHAR(500),
    TotalLike int,
    TotalComment int,
    Selflike bit,
    ShoutoutTypeId int,
    ShoutoutType NVARCHAR(200),
    PostTypeId int,
    PostTypeName NVARCHAR(200),
    oldMoment bit,
    UserLatitude numeric(20,6),
    UserLongitude numeric(20,6),
    ShoutoutLatitude numeric(20,6),
    ShoutoutLongitude numeric(20,6),
    DistanceShoutoutMiles numeric(20,6)
    )
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @StartLatitude1 numeric(20,2) = @StartLatitude
    DECLARE @StartLongitude1 numeric(20,2) =@StartLongitude;

    ;with
    UserList as (
     select
      distinct
      USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId,
      USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutGuid,
      U.UserId,
      U.FirstName,
      U.LastName,
      U.QuickbloxId,
      convert(int,round(datediff(hour,dob,getdate())/8766.0,0)) as Age,
      U.SocialId,
      U.Gender,
      U.Email,
      isnull(U.IsProfileImageSync,0) IsProfileImageSync,
      U.HomeTownCity,
      U.ImageName,
      isnull(fr.IsFriend,0) as IsFriend,
      isnull(fr.IsRequestSent,0) as IsRequestSent,
      isnull(fr.RequestSender,cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) as RequestSender,
      isnull(fr.IsBlocked,0) as IsBlocked,
      isnull(fr.FriendBlocked,0) as FriendBlocked,
      [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](cast(@StartLatitude1 as float),cast(@StartLongitude1 as float),cast (isnull(USRSHTOUT.Latitude,0) as float) ,cast(isnull(USRSHTOUT.Longitude,0) as float)) as Distance,
      (geography::Point(coalesce(USRSHTOUT.Latitude,0), coalesce(USRSHTOUT.Longitude,0), 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@StartLatitude1, @StartLongitude1, 4326))/1000) as DistanceTemp,
      ULAL.UpdatedOn as LastActiveDateTime,
      0 as InterestId,
      '' as InterestName,
      isnull(USRSHTOUT.ImageName,'') 'ShoutoutImageName',
      isnull(USRSHTOUT.Description,'') Description,USRSHTOUT.CreatedOn,IsImageSync,
      isnull(format(UGL.UpdatedOn,'dd-MMM, yyyy HH:mm tt'),'') 'DisplayUpdatedOn',
      isnull(ADC.locality,'')[ShoutoutCity],
      isnull(ADC.country,'')[ShoutoutCountry],
      isnull(ADC.administrative_area_level_1,'') [AdministrativeAreaLevel1],
      isnull(ADC.place_id,'') [PlaceId],
      isnull(ADC.formatted_address,'') FormattedAaddress,
      isnull(ADC.url,'') Url,
      isnull(lt.TotalLike, 0) as TotalLike,
      isnull(ct.TotalComment, 0) as TotalComment,
      isnull(lt.SelfLike, 0) as SelfLike,
      SHT.ShoutoutTypeId,
      isnull(SHT.Name,'') ShoutoutType,
      UPT.PostTypeId,
      isnull(UPT.Name,'') PostTypeName,
      USRSHTOUT.oldMoment,
      UGL.Latitude 'UserLatitude',
      UGL.Longitude 'UserLongitude',
      USRSHTOUT.Latitude 'ShoutoutLatitude',
      USRSHTOUT.Longitude 'ShoutoutLongitude',
      DistanceShoutoutMiles
    from
      Users U
    inner join UserShoutouts USRSHTOUT  on U.UserId=USRSHTOUT.UserId
    left join UserLastActivityLog ULAL on ULAL.UserId=U.UserId
    left join UserGeoLocation UGL on  UGL.UserId=U.UserId
    left join AddressShoutoutMapping  ASMP on ASMP.ShoutoutId=USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId
    left join AddressComponents ADC on ADC.AddressComponentId=ASMP.AddressComponentId
    left join [ShoutoutType] SHT on SHT.ShoutoutTypeId=isnull(USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutTypeId,0)
    LEFT JOIN [UserPostType] UPT ON UPT.PostTypeId = ISNULL(USRSHTOUT.PostTypeId,0)
    cross apply (select cos(radians(@StartLatitude1)) * cos(radians(USRSHTOUT.Latitude)) * cos(radians(USRSHTOUT.Longitude) - radians(@StartLongitude1)) + sin(radians(@StartLatitude1)) * sin(radians(USRSHTOUT.Latitude))) T(ACosInput)
    cross apply (select ((3959 * acos(case when abs(ACosInput) > 1 then sign(ACosInput)*1 else ACosInput end)))) T2(DistanceShoutoutMiles)
    left join (
               select ItemId,
             count(1) TotalLike,
             cast(sum(case when UserId = @anotherUserid then 1 else 0 end) as bit) as SelfLike
               from dbo.LikeDetails
               where Liked=1 and LikeSourceId=1
               group by ItemId) as lt on USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId = lt.ItemId
    left join (
               select ParentId,
             count(1) as TotalComment
               from Comments
               where CommentSourceId=1 and Comments.IsDeleted=0
               group by ParentId) as ct on USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId = ct.ParentId
    left join dbo.tvf_GetFriendsByUserId (@UserId) fr on u.UserId = fr.ThisFriendId

    left join UserShoutoutsPrivate USP on USP.ShoutoutId = USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId
    left join UserInterest UI on UI.InterestId = USP.GroupId
    left join Interest INTRST on INTRST.Id = UI.InterestId

    where
       USRSHTOUT.IsDeleted=0
       and (((@oldMoment = 0) and USRSHTOUT.oldMoment = @oldMoment)

       or ((@oldMoment = 1) and USRSHTOUT.oldMoment = 1 or USRSHTOUT.oldMoment = 0) )

       and U.IsEmailVerified=1  and isnull(U.IsDeactivated,0)=0
         and (@ShoutoutTypeId=0 or USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutTypeId=@ShoutoutTypeId)
       and (@IsMyShoutout=0 or (@IsMyShoutout=1 and USRSHTOUT.UserId = @UserId))
         and ((@UserName is not null and @UserName='all'
       OR ((U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName) = @UserName)OR (U.FirstName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName))+'%') OR (U.LastName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName))+'%'))
       OR ( @FirstName is not  null AND  @LastName is  null and
       ((U.FirstName = @FirstName ) OR (U.FirstName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName))+'%')))
       OR ( @LastName is not null AND @FirstName is null and
       ((U.LastName = @LastName ) OR (U.LastName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName))+'%')))
       OR ((( @FirstName is not null AND @LastName is not null AND
       ((U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName) = @FirstName + ' ' +  @LastName) OR (U.FirstName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName))+'%')) and (U.LastName like LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName))+'%'))))
       and((@Interest <>'' AND @IsPrivate = 1 AND (exists (select * from dbo.UserInterest where (UserId = U.UserId and InterestId in (select  * from dbo.Split(@Interest,','))))
         or @Interest ='')
       or(@IsPrivate = 1
       and (UI.Interestid in (select  items from dbo.Split(@GroupId,',')) and INTRST.IsPrivate = 1 and INTRST.IsDelete = 0 and USRSHTOUT.IsDeleted=0 and
       USP.ShoutoutId = USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId and UI.IsActive = 1 and USP.GroupId in (select  items from dbo.Split(@GroupId,','))))
       )
       OR(@Interest <>'' AND @IsPrivate = 0 AND (exists (select * from dbo.UserInterest where (UserId = U.UserId and InterestId in (select  * from dbo.Split(@Interest,','))))
         or @Interest ='')
       or(@IsPrivate = 1
       and (UI.Interestid in (select  items from dbo.Split(@GroupId,',')) and INTRST.IsPrivate = 1 and INTRST.IsDelete = 0 and USRSHTOUT.IsDeleted=0 and
       USP.ShoutoutId = USRSHTOUT.ShoutoutId and UI.IsActive = 1 and USP.GroupId in (select  items from dbo.Split(@GroupId,','))))
       )
       OR(@Interest ='' AND @IsPrivate = 0 AND (exists (select * from dbo.UserInterest where (UserId = U.UserId and InterestId in (select  * from dbo.Split(@Interest,','))))
         or @Interest =''))
       )
         and (@PostTypeId=0 or USRSHTOUT.PostTypeId=@PostTypeId)
         )

    insert into @UserList
    select
      UserId,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      QuickBloxId,
      SocialId,
      Gender,
      Email,
      IsProfileImageSync,
      IsFriend,
      IsRequestSent,
      RequestSender,
      IsBlocked,
      FriendBlocked,
      Age,
      HomeTownCity,
      ImageName,
      Distance,
      DistanceTemp,
      LastActiveDateTime,
      ShoutoutGuid,
      ShoutoutId,
      InterestId,
      InterestName,
      ShoutoutImageName,
      Description,
      CreatedOn,
      IsImageSync,
      DisplayUpdatedOn,
      ShoutoutCity,
      ShoutoutCountry,
      AdministrativeAreaLevel1,
      PlaceId,
      FormattedAaddress,
      Url,
      u.TotalLike,
      u.TotalComment,
      u.Selflike,
      ShoutoutTypeId,
      ShoutoutType,
      PostTypeId,
      PostTypeName,
      oldMoment,
      UserLatitude,
      UserLongitude,
      ShoutoutLatitude,
      ShoutoutLongitude,
      DistanceShoutoutMiles
    from  UserList u
       where
       (@Gender ='' or ((Gender in(select  * from dbo.Split(@Gender,','))) or (@Gender like '%3%' and Gender=0)))
       and(
          ((@AgeFrom = 18) AND ((@AgeTo= 65 and Age >= 15 )
        or (Age >= 15 and Age <= @AgeTo)))
        OR
        ((@AgeTo= 65 and Age >= @AgeFrom )
        or (Age >= @AgeFrom and Age <= @AgeTo))
        )

       and IsBlocked <> 1
       and FriendBlocked <> 1
       and (@Location=0 or ((DistanceShoutoutMiles<= @Radius) or (@IsLocal=1 and HomeTownCity=@HomeTownCity)))
       and (@IsFriend=0 or (@IsFriend=1 and IsFriend=1))
       and (@Location=0 or (
       ((@IsTraveler=1 and @IsLocal=1) or (@IsTraveler=0 and @IsLocal=0)) or
       ((@IsTraveler=1 and @IsLocal=0 and lower(HomeTownCity) != lower(@HomeTownCity))
       or (@IsTraveler=0 and @IsLocal=1 and lower(HomeTownCity) = lower(@HomeTownCity)))))OPTION(RECOMPILE)
       set @TotalRows = @@rowcount
       IF(@CurrentPage=0)
        begin
          select * from @UserList order by Distance asc    OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
        end
      ELSE
        BEGIN
          declare @OffSetSize as bigint
          set @OffSetSize = ((@CurrentPage * @PageSize) - @PageSize)
          IF (@SortExpression = '1')
            BEGIN
              SELECT *
              FROM @UserList
              WHERE CreatedOn<@CreatedDate
              ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
              OFFSET @OffSetSize ROWS
              FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
               OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
            END
          ELSE IF (@SortExpression = '2')
              BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM @UserList
                WHERE CreatedOn>@CreatedDate
                ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
                OFFSET @OffSetSize ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
                 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
              END
          ELSE IF (@SortExpression = '3')
              BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM @UserList
                ORDER BY Distance ASC, CreatedOn DESC
                OFFSET @OffSetSize ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
                 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
           END
           ELSE IF (@SortExpression = '4')
              BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM @UserList
                ORDER BY Distance ASC
                OFFSET @OffSetSize ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
                 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
           END
            ELSE
              BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM @UserList
                ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
                OFFSET @OffSetSize ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
                 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
              END
        END

    ENDGO
```

Comment: Without looking at how you are managing the connection with the server, It is hard to provide any help.

Comment: Use`OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to recompile the queries every time it is run.  The underlying statistics are getting out of synch with the stashed query plans.

Comment: Should I add sp code here ?

Comment: Although the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint @GordonLinoff suggested is probably a good fit here to avoid parameter sniffing, I would not use it in cases where the proc is executed frequently (e.g. many times a second). Dynamic SQL might be a better solution as detailed [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) in that case.

Comment: Are you changing the definition of the tables (objects) the SP is referencing and using `SELECT *` within the SP's definition by any chance..?

Comment: I have added SP code, please help on this.

Comment: "stop working" doesn't mean anythhing. Please expand on this

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it's so simple, I have this SP on my window server and used in mobile  API created with c#.

 As you can see this SP return "Shoutouts" data, but some stop coming, than i need to select that SP as alter query (as showing above in code ) and execute, then it again start returning records.

Comment: With queries like that, I suggest having a read of [#BackToBasics: An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: "some stop coming" only means a little more than "stop working" Are you saying that after a while the proc returns less records than it should?

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is not on the client side ?. Depending on your language you could have a persistent query object that mixes the parameters values between calls. If that's the case then you just have to empty all the parameters at every call, before assigning the new values for the parameters chosen by the user. By the way, I fully support @GordonLinoff suggestion that this query needs an OPTION(RECOMPILE) to be executed efficiently.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I mean,  after one or two  days, proc didn't  return any data.